# Is $\phi_*X\in\mathfrak{X}(H)$ left invariant if $X\in\mathfrak{X}(G)$ is left invariant and $\phi\colon G\to H$ is a Lie group homomorphism?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, group-homomorphism, pushforward

Let $G$ and $H$ be Lie groups and let $\phi\colon G\to H$ be a Lie group homomorphism. If $X\in\mathfrak{X}(G)$ is left invariant, is $\phi_*X\in\mathfrak{X}(H)$ (the pushforward of $X$ under $\phi$) left invariant, too?

**Here is why I ask this**: Let $e$ and $e'$ be the neutral elements of $G$ and $H$. In the book I am currently reading, $\mathfrak{g}\subset\mathfrak{X}(G)$ is the set of left invariant vector fields and $\phi_*\colon\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
(\phi_*X)_{e'}=\mathrm{d}\phi_eX_e,
\end{equation}
where the right side is just the usual pushforward evaluated at $e=\phi^{-1}(e')$ and one needs to remember that left-invariant vector field are uniquely determined by their value at one point.

Of course, that leads to the question whether two different vector fields are denoted by $\phi_*X$, the usual pushforward and the left invariant vector field with the same value at $e'$. If the answer to my question is yes, this is not a problem, since $\phi_*\colon\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$ is just the restriction of the pushforward $\phi_*\colon\mathfrak{X}(G)\to\mathfrak{X}(H)$ to left invariant vector fields.

Comment: The pushforward isn't defined for general Lie group homomorphisms. What one can say instead is that given a left-invariant field $X\in\mathfrak{X}G$ there is a unique left-invariant field $Y\in\mathfrak{X}H$ which is $\phi$-related to $X$.

Comment: @Kajelad Thank you for the comment! In the book I am currently reading, a Lie group homomorphism is by definition differentiable (even smooth), thus the differential $\mathrm{d}\phi_g$ exists for all $g\in G$ and therefore the pushforward is well-defined.

Comment: That isn't sufficient for the pushforward of vector fields to be well defined. Take the projection $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, for example.

Comment: @Kajelad Thank you for the reply. $\textbf{Firstly}$: Indeed, the differentiability of $\phi$ is not sufficient for $\phi_*$ to be well defined. In the book I mentioned the pushforward is defined by $(\phi_*X)_{\phi(p)}=\mathrm{d}\phi_pX_p$ and if one doesn't properly think about the equation (like me), one might think that only the existence of the differential of $\phi$ is assumed. But of course, what the equation really means is $(\phi_*X)_q=\mathrm{d}\phi_{\phi^{-1}(q)}X_{\phi^{-1}(q)}$ and thus $\phi$ also needs to be invertible!

Comment: $\textbf{Secondly}$: I looked into John Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" and $\phi_*X$ is defined as the unique vector field $\phi$-related to $X$ ($\phi$ is assumed to be a diffeomorphism). Thus, in the situtation where $\phi$ is a differentiable Lie group homomorphism $\textbf{and}$ a diffeomorphism, the two definitions of $\phi_*$ are equal, so there is no ambiguity. (I hope what I say is correct.)

Comment: That's correct. Furthermore, when looking at an arbitrary homomorphism $\phi:G\to H$, for an arbitrary field $X\in\mathfrak{X}G$ the $\phi$-related vector field may neither exist nor be unique (so no pushforward), but if we restrict attention to left-invariant vector fields on both sides, we get both existence and uniqueness.

Comment: @Kajelad Interesting! Do you have a reference for this (if $X\in\mathfrak{X}(G)$ is left invariant and $\phi$ is an homomorphism, there is exactly one left invariant $Y\in\mathfrak{X}(H)$ that is $\phi$-related to $X$)?

Comment: This is theorem 8.44 in Lee.

Comment: @Kajelad Thank you very much! Thanks to this discussion I now have a much better understanding of the symbol $\phi_*$ :)